# Constant space restriction on an array SDE interview questions. A doubts for a classic interview questions

Tags: arrays

You are given an array [a1 To an] and we have to construct another array [b1 To bn] where `bi = a1*a2*…*an/ai`. you are allowed to use only constant space and the time complexity is O(n). No divisions are allowed.

The logic of solution is quite simple, remove the bi from the product to get the result. However, when I processed to solve this problem I found myself be trapped.  Here is my doubts:

According to my understanding, the constant space here means despite the length of the array, the number of variables I can use have to be fixed. Which forbids to create a new arrays to solve the problem. Because creating new arrays makes the number of variables different when dealing with different arrays.

I have searched most solution for this online, however all the solutions I can find created new arrays. 
So, did I miss anything here?  Any thoughts? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to use array indices from 0 to N-1 because that's how we do things in the hood.

You can rewrite the equation for b<sub>i</sub> like this:  b<sub>i</sub> = (a<sub>0</sub>×a<sub>1</sub>×⋯×a<sub>i-1</sub>) × (a<sub>i+1</sub>×a<sub>i+2</sub>×⋯×a<sub>n-1</sub>), or more succinctly like this: b<sub>i</sub> = (∏<sub>j=0⋯i-1</sub> a<sub>j</sub>) × (∏<sub>j=i+1⋯n-1</sub> a<sub>j</sub>).

(In case you're not familiar with it, ∏ is like ∑ but it multiplies the terms instead of adding them.  Also, these formulas are not *quite* the same as the formula in your question, because according to the formula in your question, b<sub>i</sub> is undefined if a<sub>i</sub> is zero.  However, I will assume that the intent is to cancel the a<sub>i</sub> in the numerator and denominator, even if it is zero.)

**Anyway**, you can compute the left subproducts (∏<sub>j=0⋯i-1</sub> a<sub>j</sub>) incrementally by traversing array a from 0 to n-1.  You can compute the right subproducts (∏<sub>j=i+1⋯n-1</sub> a<sub>j</sub>) by traversing the array a from n-1 to 0.

Thus the solution is to use two passes.

The first pass is from 0 to N-1.  Set each `b[i]` to the product of `a[j]` for `0 <= j < i`.  This pass sets the b array to the left subproducts.  This takes O(N) time and constant space for the loop counter.

The second pass is from N-1 to 0.  Update each `b[i]` by multiplying it by the product of `a[j]` for `i < j < N`.  Thus pass updates the b array by multiplying each element by the appropriate right subproduct.  This takes O(N) time and constant space for the loop counter and a temporary.

Here's a Python solution:

```
b[0] = 1
for i in range(1, N):
    b[i] = b[i - 1] * a[i - 1]

# Now every b[i] is the product of the a[j] where 0 <= j < i.

t = 1
for i in range(N-1, -1, -1):
    b[i] = b[i] * t
    t *= a[i]

# Now every b[i] is the product of the a[j] where 0 <= j < i
# and the a[j] where i < j <= N-1.  This is the desired output.
```

Answer (score 1):

A constant space requirement doesn't forbid the creation of new arrays. It just means that your algorithm needs to use the same amount of space each time it runs. Since the question asks you to construct a new array, I'm going to show a function that does this with constant space and in linear time.

You can still create a new array. Just make sure that it's a constant size. The easiest way to do this is to make it the largest possible size. For example, in C++ you could use

```
int* b  = new int[UINT_MAX];
```

since the largest index that be used in array is UINT_MAX. Here is a solution that is both linear time, constant space, and constructs a new array as desired.

```
int* prod(int *a, int len) {
    int* b  = new int[UINT_MAX];
    int tmp = 1;
    b[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i += 1) b[i] = b[i - 1] * a[i - 1];
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        b[i] = b[i] * tmp;
        tmp *= a[i];
    } // for
    return b;
} // prod
```

The contract of the function should be that the size of the new array is the same as the input array (even though we secretly know it's bigger). This, of course, is not as efficient as calculating it in-place, but that's NOT what the question is asking (at least the way that it's worded).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this:

```
/* size = size of the original array*/ 
/* orgArr = the original array with the numbers*/

int i; 
int temp = 1;
int *result = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
memset(result, 1, size);

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   result[i] = temp;
   temp *= orgArr[i];
}

temp = 1;
for(i= n-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   result[i] *= temp;
   temp *= OrgArr[i];
}
```

Space Complexity => O(n)
Time Complexity => O(n)

You can make this a constant space by using UINT_MAX for the result instead of size.

Comment: That's O(n) space. She needs O(1) space.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the problem,

- You are given an array [a1 .. an]
- construct another array [b1 .. bn] where bi = a1*a2*…*an/ai
- you are allowed to use only constant space and the time complexity is O(n)
- No divisions are allowed

The naive approach would be to use division, and compute everything in place, once,

```
#!/bin/env ruby #because I can
n = aray.size - 1
prod = 1
0.upto(n) { |x| prod *= aray[x] } 
0.upto(n) { |x| bray[x] = (aray[x]==0) ? 0 : prod/aray[x] }
```

*Note that I used bray[], but could have easily just emitted the result, or replaced aray[]*

But the problem statement does not allow division.  Too bad.

So instead, we need to keep around the original values, placing the result into bray[],
where we loop through aray[] twice, computing the product from left to right, and then
back from right to left,

```
#!/bin/env ruby #because I can
aray = [ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31 ]
bray = [ ]
n = aray.size-1
prod = 1
0.upto(n) { |ndx| bray[ndx] = prod; prod *= aray[ndx]; }
prod = 1
n.downto(0) { |ndx| bray[ndx] *= prod; prod *= aray[ndx]; }
```

Print the results,

```
print "aray:\n";
aray.each_index { |ndx| print "[#{ndx}] #{aray[ndx]}\n" }
print "bray:\n";
bray.each_index { |ndx| print "[#{ndx}] #{bray[ndx]}\n" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is core part of the program.

Given

a[i] where i ranges from 0 to n-1

b[i] where i ranges from 0 to n-1.

Assume n = 4 for demo purpose

CODE Starts HERE

```
int count,sum=1;
for(count = 0; count < n; count++)
{
b[count] = sum;
sum *= a[count];
}
/*
```

Loop with count = 0

```
b[0] = 1;
sum = a[0]
```

Loop with count = 1

```
b[1] = a[0]
sum = a[0] a[1]
```

Loop with count = 2

```
b[2] = a[0] a[1]
sum = a[0] a[1] a[2]
```

Loop with count = 3

```
b[3] = a[0] a[1] a[2]
sum = a[0] a[1] a[2] a[3] -- This sum is not used at all
```

At the end of the LOOP

```
b[0] = 1;
b[1] = a[0]
b[2] = a[0] a[1]
b[3] = a[0] a[1] a[2]

*/
sum = 1;
for(count = n-1; count >= 0; count--)
{
b[count] *= sum;
sum *= a[count];
}
/*
```

At the start of LOOP

```
b[3] = a[0] a[1] a[2]
b[2] = a[0] a[1]
b[1] = a[0]
b[0] = 1;
```

Loop with count = 3

```
b[3] = a[0] a[1] a[2] -- multiplied with 1 will lead to the same answer
sum = a[3]
```

Loop with count = 2

```
b[2] = a[0] a[1] a[3]
sum = a[3] a[2]
```

Loop with count = 1

```
b[1] = a[0] a[2] a[3]
sum = a[3] a[2] a[1]
```

Loop with count = 0

```
b[0] = a[1] a[2] a[3] -- Multiplied with 1 will lead to the same answer
sum = a[3] a[2] a[1] a[0] -- This sum is not used at all.
```

At the end of the LOOP

```
b[0] = a[1] a[2] a[3] 
b[1] = a[0] a[2] a[3]
b[2] = a[0] a[1] a[3]
b[3] = a[0] a[1] a[2]
```

*/